# django customize self._errors

Tags: python, django

I'm overriding the clean method for my variables and want to specify a custom error message on error.

```
myErrorMsg = "This is my error Message"
myErrorMsg += "\nThis is my error Message I would like on the next line"
self._errors["mytag"] = myErrorMsg
```

However it seems to ignore all line breaks I tried both html `<br />` and `\n` but nothing works everything gets put on one line and I loose capitalization.

Comment: Please properly format code in your posts; you've asked over 100 questions so you should have figured it out by now. If you need help, click the orange question mark at the top right corner of the post entry box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tried inserting a <br /> tag, did it literally show up in the output as "<br />"?  If so, then Django is automatically escaping the error message.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping for more details.

Comment: fantastic thank you that was exactly it, the only other problem is I loose capitalization

Comment: @user391986 don't forget to accept the answer by clickig a tick near it.

Comment: Is there any way to also not loose the capitals? It seems everything goes to lower case and first letter gets capitalized

Comment: Are you using the "|cap" filter on the message output?

Answer (score 2):

```
self._errors["mytag"] = self._errors.get("mytag", self.error_class())
self._errors["mytag"].append("This is my error Message")
self._errors["mytag"].append("This is my error Message I would like on the next line")
```

but it was like two errors. 
about escaping was saying. 
try

```
...
self._errors["mytag"].append(mark_safe("text<br/>text"))
```

or

```
self._errors["mytag"] = self.error_class([mark_safe("text<br/>text")])
```